# Orphaned printers on Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: printing, network-printer, windows-server-2012-r2

Somehow all my printers (which are shared) is missing on my server.

If I click "Add a printer", then all my printers are shown even though they were deleted...

[image]

I've tried to manually install one of the printers and when I print, I get this error in the eventlog:

"The document Print Document, owned by administrator, failed to print on printer TAA_Print_1. Try to print the document again, or restart the print spooler. 
Data type: RAW. Size of the spool file in bytes: 197154. Number of bytes printed: 0. Total number of pages in the document: 1. Number of pages printed: 0. Client computer: \SVFREJA. Win32 error code returned by the print processor: 5. Access is denied."

Here's a screencast:

[Screen cast of problem](http://screencast.com/t/pYRz2pbvhb)

Any ideas?

Comment: The listed printers are the printers that were told to be listed in Active Directory, not the printers installed on the machine.  Are/were these printers hosted from the same server you're trying to add them too?  When you install them and "can't print", what actually happens when you try? What have you tried already to diagnose this? If you manually add one of the as a new printer, using the right driver, does it work?  Anything in your Event Logs related to the printers or printing?  Is the printer spooler actually running?

Comment: I've updated my post with error from Eventlog and a screencast of the problem. No, no matter how I install the printer, it doesn't work. Yes printer spooler is running.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the directory C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS had write-permission removed, so after granting write-permission, everything worked.